# Show comment through parent post id in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, continuous-integration, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating wall script like facebook. I am new in Angularjs.
My problem is I am showing all post from database through controller which is display fine.
Now I have to show that post comments below parent post. I am using ng-repeat="comment in comments" for this but now all comment repeat in all post.

Can you tell me show to display comments data according to parent id?

This is my code:

```
commentlist:function(data,scope)
        {

                var dataObject = {
          communityid : data
       };
            $http.post(ApiAccessUrl+"/community/commentlist/DADA-APIKEY/"+APIKEY, dataObject, {})
         .success(function(data){

               angular.forEach(data.commentlist, function(value, key) {
                   var dataObject = {
          timestamp : value.comment_date_time
       };

                   $http.post(ApiAccessUrl+"/community/timestamp/DADA-APIKEY/"+APIKEY, dataObject, {})
         .success(function(data){ 
          var outputDate=angular.fromJson(data);
           var full_name=ucfirst(value.mem_fname)+" "+ucfirst(value.mem_lname); 

              var photo='value.photo;
                scope.comments.unshift({full_name:full_name,photo:photo,comment:value.comment_comment,timestamp:outputDate});
         });
```

Comment: please show your ng-repeat code, can't help otherwise

Comment: <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
<a href="" class="size13">{{comment.full_name}}</a>
 <span class="size12">
              {{comment.comment}}  
              </span>
</div>

Comment: <div ng-controller="communityController">
        <div ng-repeat="community_data in communitys">

</div></div> this is parent controller which show all post..

Comment: I am using service to call comments but I need to display comment below it's parent post not all post.

Comment: only I need that code which is show post with it's own comment. like 10 post with post comment in angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if comment has postId, then you can do ng-repeat like this

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts"> 
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter : {'postId' : post.Id }"> 
       <a href="" class="size13">{{comment.full_name}}</a> 
       <span class="size12"> {{comment.comment}} </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I do that same but problem is that post which have no comments it's display above post comments.

Comment: Thank you Very Much harish your are awesome. it's work fine when I apply filter according to you... but not getting what this filter do...

Comment: can you please accept the answer... the above filter is basically filtering the comment by post.Id